# Large Login Box on Lockscreen

Tags: encryption, lightdm, lock-screen, budgie

I am running Ubuntu Budgie 18.04, and I'm having some bizarre issues with the password/login box on the lockscreen. This only happens on the screen where I actually lock my laptop.

This doesn't happen on my desktop. The only significant difference between my laptop and desktop is that I have full disk encryption setup on my laptop.

[image: Lockscreen]

lightdm-settings HiDPi setting doesn't appear to change anything.

Is there a way to make the login box not so ridiculous?

---

I have checked that it is not theme related; I use Adapta, but this also happens with Pocillo. I even tried swapping out Slick Greeter with LightDM Greeter and I get the same results. This is even a fresh install from yesterday morning. The install before that also had the issue.

---

After a bit of messing around, I've determined it's a scaling issue. My display is 3000x2000, and when I set the GUI scaling to 100% (200% being the default with this screen) the size of the box is more appropriate to the scale.

Comment: I've tried removing gnome-screensaver to replace it with light-locker, but the removal also wants to remove budgie-desktop and others. Would you be able to point me towards a resource that could show me how to disable gnome-screensaver or remove it without removing Budgie?

Comment: you can't - the code needs changing to remove the lock screen dependency on gnome-screensaver.  Better to figure out what needs to change in gnome-screensaver.

Comment: As in configuration or bug report?

I couldn't find the method in which one configures gnome-screensaver.

Comment: run "ubuntu-bug gnome-screensaver" in a terminal session to report a bug.